# How to display a collection item in a JSP Page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

For other reasons I have to do a forEach loop on a jsp page rather than iterating over a collection.  I need to display the value of a collection, but I am returning a syntax error because of the inner braces..do I have to escape it first?  How do I get it to resolve the value of i then to get the value from the colllection?

```
  <c:if test="${maxColumns >= 0}">  
     <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${maxColumns}" step="1" varStatus ="status">
     <td height="20"> ${columnNames[${i}].columnName</td>
</c:forEach>
  </c:if>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `${columnNames[i].columnName}` doesn't work? That said, IMO this is work better done outside of the view layer, and returning a subset of a collection is trivial. Why not do that instead?

Comment: yes it does work!! I never even thought about taking out the inner braces because I thought it was neccessary to resolve that value first. I tried everything except that!! Thanks so much.  Also to answer your question I do have to show the entire collection but I have to display them in a particular manner based on values from another collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest JSP EL expressions like that, but you don't have to--the correct expression is:

```
${columnNames[i].columnName}
```

`i` is already part of the EL scope because of the `forEach` tag, and should be evaluated as any other scoped variable, like `columnNames`. Here it's just a collection index.

While I'm sympathetic to the perceived need to do this kind of logic in the view layer, IMO it's almost always a better idea to prep collection ranges in Java--it's also easier to test.